# ActiveRecord for core data

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, activerecord

i use this library: https://github.com/jwang/activerecord-fetching-for-core-data

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    if (managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSString *modelPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"BranchData" ofType:@"momd"];
    NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:modelPath];
    managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];    
return managedObjectModel;

}

///////

[NSManagedObjectModel setDefaultManagedObjectModel:self.managedObjectModel];
[ActiveRecordHelpers setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:@"BranchData.sqlite"];


NSManagedObjectContext *context = [NSManagedObjectContext context];
[NSManagedObjectContext setDefaultContext:context];


NSLog(@"%i", [[DataBranch findAll] count]);

DataBranch *branch = [DataBranch createEntity];

NSLog(@"%i", [[DataBranch findAll] count]);

[[NSManagedObjectContext context] save];
```

It works the logs prints out 0 and then 1
But if i restart my application it is not saved into the sqlite. and all data is lost
what do i do wrong ?

Comment: [NSManagedObjectContext context]? Is that correct? I don't think NSManagedObjectContext has a method named "context."

Comment: It uses that category methods from the library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confused the context i needed to save to the defaultContext and not the context as it woul create a new one

Answer (score 0):

You need to use createInContext method instead of createEntity

```
    DataBranch *branch = [DataBranch createInContext:context];
```